# How to set constraints to multiple UIImageView's in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, constraints

After hours of attempting to find a solution, as well as trying and failing myself I decided to ask here.

As shown on the picture below I have 15 Image views in a pyramid shape that I would like to set constraints on.

[image]

I have tried to:

1. Constraint equal width and height on all images
2. Constraint center image on line 1, 3 and 5 to horizontal center
3. Align vertical centers to all images on each line
4. Etc etc

The result is always the image view going out of bounds or similar issues. (Clip to Bounds is true)

Anyone have a solution or suggestions?

Comment: It isn't clear what your constraints should be (not in code, but what layout you are after). Is the size of the individual views fixed, or proportional to the available screen size? How about the horizontal/vertical margins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try putting them all in stack views then putting all those stack views inside a stack view and putting constraints on that

like this take a look at the view hierarchy on the left

[image: image 1]

to get the spacing i achieved just adjust the spacing on the right inside the attributes inspector

and its even able to have constraints on the highest stack view

[image: image 2]

all the errors go away once you add constraints to the top stack view

like shown here

[image: image 3]

Comment: no, it is possible to add width, height, leading, trailing etc. besides he does not need constraints inside stack view i will upload image to show what i mean

Comment: you can only add contraint inside stackview if there is another view inside stackview  stackview>View>elements(now only, you can add contraint )

Comment: let me upload image to show what i meant check my answer for visual on what i meant

Comment: i achieved his exact problem and without using constraints doing exactly what i said was possible with stack views

Comment: see your view controller it self shows the constraints error

Comment: but.....the error went away once i added constraints check my answer the final image shows constraints and no errors

Comment: oh! as because you have't add any constraints inside your stackview Right. (my point is that.)

Comment: Used this method. Thanks for letting me know about how helpful Stack Views can be.

Comment: im glad i could help! you should learn to use stackviews they are extremely useful for UI building

Answer (score 0):

Embed all your imageViews in a UIView.

set the top, bottom, leading and trailing constraint inside that view (top image to the superview, etc.).

align the UIView horizontally and vertically in the container.

You probably also want to set a width to your UIView, but I let you think about the final result you want.